# Vagrant/Puppet with Django -- What's the URL?

Tags: python, django, nginx, vagrant, puppet

I've been using Vagrant/Puppet successfully in an Apache/MySQL/PHP setup, but now I'm trying to do a Python/Django setup. A popular Github repo had some files, and they were outdated -- i corrected them and I get no errors when running Vagrant or Puppet, but I can't access it.

Here are my files:

**VagrantFile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
  # config.vm.box_url = "http://puppet-vagrant-boxes.puppetlabs.com/ubuntu-1310-x64-virtualbox-puppet.box"

  # Boot with a GUI so you can see the screen. (Default is headless)
  # config.vm.boot_mode = :gui

  # Assign this VM to a host-only network IP, allowing you to access it
  # via the IP. Host-only networks can talk to the host machine as well as
  # any other machines on the same network, but cannot be accessed (through this
  # network interface) by any external networks.
  # config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.33.10"

  # Assign this VM to a bridged network, allowing you to connect directly to a
  # network using the host's network device. This makes the VM appear as another
  # physical device on your network.
  # config.vm.network :bridged

  # Forward a port from the guest to the host, which allows for outside
  # computers to access the VM, whereas host only networking does not.
  # config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # an identifier, the second is the path on the guest to mount the
  # folder, and the third is the path on the host to the actual folder.
  # config.vm.share_folder "v-data", "/vagrant_data", "../data"

  # Provisioning
  config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
    shell.inline = "mkdir -p /etc/puppet/modules;
      #              (puppet module install stankevich-python; true)
                     "
  end


  # Enable provisioning with Puppet stand alone.  Puppet manifests
  # are contained in a directory path relative to this Vagrantfile.
  # You will need to create the manifests directory and a manifest in
  # the file site.pp in the manifests_path directory.
  #
  # An example Puppet manifest to provision the message of the day:
  #
  # # group { "puppet":
  # #   ensure => "present",
  # # }
  # #
  # # File { owner => 0, group => 0, mode => 0644 }
  # #
  # # file { '/etc/motd':
  # #   content => "Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine!
  # #               Managed by Puppet.\n"
  # # }
  #
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    #puppet.facter = {
    #    "fqdn" => "dev.pm.com",
    #    "aliases" => "*.dev.pm.com",
    #    "hostname" => "dev",
    #    "docroot" => '/var/www/html/',
    #}
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
  end
end
```

**site.pp**

```
Exec { path => '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin' }

# Global variables
$inc_file_path = '/vagrant/manifests/files' # Absolute path to the files directory (If you're using vagrant, you can leave it alone.)
$tz = 'America/Los_Angeles' # Timezone
$user = 's98' # User to create
$password = 'password' # The user's password
$project = 's98pm' # Used in nginx and uwsgi
$domain_name = 'dev.pm.com' # Used in nginx, uwsgi and virtualenv directory
$db_name = 's98pm' # Mysql database name to create
$db_user = 'pmadmin' # Mysql username to create
$db_password = 'pass123' # Mysql password for $db_user

include timezone
include user
include apt
include nginx
#include python
include uwsgi
include mysql
include virtualenv
include pildeps
include software

class timezone {
  package { "tzdata":
    ensure => latest,
    require => Class['apt']
  }

  file { "/etc/localtime":
    require => Package["tzdata"],
    source => "file:///usr/share/zoneinfo/${tz}",
  }
}

class user {
  exec { 'add user':
    command => "sudo useradd -m -G sudo -s /bin/bash ${user}",
    unless => "id -u ${user}"
  }

  exec { 'set password':
    command => "echo \"${user}:${password}\" | sudo chpasswd",
    require => Exec['add user']
  }

  # Prepare user's project directories
  file { ["/home/${user}/virtualenvs",
          "/home/${user}/public_html",
          "/home/${user}/public_html/${domain_name}",
          "/home/${user}/public_html/${domain_name}/static"
          ]:
    ensure => directory,
    owner => "${user}",
    group => "${user}",
    require => Exec['add user'],
    before => File['media dir']
  }

  file { 'media dir':
    path => "/home/${user}/public_html/${domain_name}/media",
    ensure => directory,
    owner => "${user}",
    group => 'www-data',
    mode => 0775,
    require => Exec['add user']
  }
}

class apt {
  exec { 'apt-get update':
    timeout => 0
  }

  package { 'python-software-properties':
    ensure => latest,
    require => Exec['apt-get update']
  }

  exec { 'add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable':
    require => Package['python-software-properties'],
    before => Exec['last ppa']
  }

  exec { 'last ppa':
    command => 'add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa',
    require => Package['python-software-properties']
  }

  exec { 'apt-get update again':
    command => 'apt-get update',
    timeout => 0,
    require => Exec['last ppa']
  }
}

class nginx {
  package { 'nginx':
    ensure => latest,
    require => Class['apt']
  }

  service { 'nginx':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
    require => Package['nginx']
  }

  file { '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default':
    ensure => absent,
    require => Package['nginx']
  }

  file { 'sites-available config':
    path => "/etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain_name}",
    ensure => file,
    content => template("${inc_file_path}/nginx/nginx.conf.erb"),
    require => Package['nginx']
  }

  file { "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/${domain_name}":
    ensure => link,
    target => "/etc/nginx/sites-available/${domain_name}",
    require => File['sites-available config'],
    notify => Service['nginx']
  }
}

package { 'curl':
  ensure => latest,
  require => Class['apt']
}

class { 'python':
  version    => 'system',
  pip        => true,
  dev        => true,
  virtualenv => true,
  gunicorn   => true,
}

class uwsgi {
  $sock_dir = '/tmp/uwsgi' # Without a trailing slash
  $uwsgi_user = 'www-data'
  $uwsgi_group = 'www-data'

  package { 'uwsgi':
    ensure => latest,
    provider => pip,
    require => Class['python']
  }

  service { 'uwsgi':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
    require => File['apps-enabled config']
  }

  # Prepare directories
  file { ['/var/log/uwsgi', '/etc/uwsgi', '/etc/uwsgi/apps-available', '/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled']:
    ensure => directory,
    require => Package['uwsgi'],
    before => File['apps-available config']
  }

  # Prepare a directory for sock file
  file { [$sock_dir]:
    ensure => directory,
    owner => "${uwsgi_user}",
    require => Package['uwsgi']
  }

  # Upstart file
  file { '/etc/init/uwsgi.conf':
    ensure => file,
    source => "${inc_file_path}/uwsgi/uwsgi.conf",
    require => Package['uwsgi']
  }

  # Vassals ini file
  file { 'apps-available config':
    path => "/etc/uwsgi/apps-available/${project}.ini",
    ensure => file,
    content => template("${inc_file_path}/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini.erb")
  }

  file { 'apps-enabled config':
    path => "/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/${project}.ini",
    ensure => link,
    target => "/etc/uwsgi/apps-available/${project}.ini",
    require => File['apps-available config']
  }
}

class mysql {
  $create_db_cmd = "CREATE DATABASE ${db_name} CHARACTER SET utf8;"
  $create_user_cmd = "CREATE USER '${db_user}'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '${db_password}';"
  $grant_db_cmd = "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${db_name}.* TO '${db_user}'@localhost;"

  package { 'mysql-server':
    ensure => latest,
    require => Class['apt']
  }

  package { 'libmysqlclient-dev':
    ensure => latest,
    require => Class['apt']
  }

  service { 'mysql':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
    require => Package['mysql-server']
  }

  exec { 'grant user db':
    command => "mysql -u root -e \"${create_db_cmd}${create_user_cmd}${grant_db_cmd}\"",
    unless => "mysqlshow -u${db_user} -p${db_password} ${db_name}",
    require => Service['mysql']
  }
}

class virtualenv {
  package { 'virtualenv':
    ensure => latest,
    provider => pip,
    require => Class['python', 'user']
  }

  exec { 'create virtualenv':
    command => "virtualenv ${domain_name}",
    cwd => "/home/${user}/virtualenvs",
    user => $user,
    creates => "/home/${user}/virtualenvs/${domain_name}",
    require => Package['virtualenv']
  }

  file { "/home/${user}/virtualenvs/${domain_name}/requirements.txt":
    ensure => file,
    owner => "${user}",
    group => "${user}",
    mode => 0644,
    source => "${inc_file_path}/virtualenv/requirements.txt",
    require => Exec['create virtualenv']
  }
}

class pildeps {
  package { ['python-imaging', 'libjpeg-dev', 'libfreetype6-dev']:
    ensure => latest,
    require => Class['apt'],
    before => Exec['pil png', 'pil jpg', 'pil freetype']
  }

  exec { 'pil png':
    command => 'sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/',
    unless => 'test -L /usr/lib/libz.so'
  }

  exec { 'pil jpg':
    command => 'sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/',
    unless => 'test -L /usr/lib/libjpeg.so'
  }

  exec { 'pil freetype':
    command => 'sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/',
    unless => 'test -L /usr/lib/libfreetype.so'
  }
}

class software {
  package { 'git':
    ensure => latest,
    require => Class['apt']
  }

  package { 'vim':
    ensure => latest,
    require => Class['apt']
  }
}
```

I have tried to access the following URLs:
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1:8000
dev.pm.com
dev.pm.com:8000

What am I missing?

Comment: You've been accessing them from within `vagrant ssh`? What does `netstat -tlnp` say in there?

Comment: I changed my config because a lot of the data was old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to access the app running inside Vagrant from outside of the VM. In order to do so, the inner port on which your Django app is running inside the VM must be forwarded to the host. Using the Vagrantfile API v2, this is how it's done:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8000, guest: 80
```

This tells Vagrant now that, as your app is running on port 80 inside your VM (guest) (at least I assume it is as you have an nginx configuration), to forward that port 80 to port 8000 on your host machine. So if you start the VM with this config, any server running inside the VM on port 80 will be accessible from your host machine on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Comment: I think you were right on this, but I had moved on on my config as it was using a bunch of outdated ideas and cannot delete this question.